How do I programmatically (via Python/xlWings) add axes to an existing chart?
I have a very odd problem.
I have a python script that adds data every week to an existing Excel spreadsheet to track a weekly metric I'm interested in.  When it pastes the new data in the existing worksheet, the chart that tracks the data loses its horizontal and vertical axes (probalby some Excel or Pandas.ExcelWriter issue; would love to solve that, but that's not the purpose of this post).
I'm trying to have the python script re-add the missing axes, but can't find anything in the xlwings .api that will readd it. I can add titles, text, etc.. but not sure how to actually add the axes back.
I thought maybe tickling the axes would cause them to reappear, such as:
sheet = book.sheets['Criticality_Over_Time']
chart = sheet.charts[0]
chart.api[1].Axes(xl.constants.AxisType.xlCategory, xl.constants.AxisGroup.xlPrimary).MajorUnitIsAuto = True
chart.api[1].Axes(xl.constants.AxisType.xlCategory, xl.constants.AxisGroup.xlPrimary).MinorUnitIsAuto = True

Is there a way to re-add the axes?  I've serached everywhere and can't find a good example.

It may depend on exactly what happened in your chart. 
However if you had Axis on your chart and they were deleted the following code should re-enable.
Example if the following chart which has a Primary (Series Batch 1 and Batch 2) and Secondary (Batch 3) Y (Verticle) Axis and Primary X (Horizontal) Axis that have all been deleted

The code checks each data series and enables the (Primary or Secondary) X and Y Axis for the series. 
The same as checking the boxes in the Axis Elements in the chart 'Format Axis'


import xlwings as xw

### Constants
msoElementPrimaryValueAxisShow = 353
msoElementSecondaryValueAxisShow = 363
msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisShow = 349
msoElementSecondaryCategoryAxisShow = 359

filename = 'chart.xlsx'
sheet = 'Sheet1'

with xw.App(visible=True) as xl:
    wb = xl.books.open(filename)
    ws = wb.sheets[sheet]

    for chart in ws.charts:
        for series in chart.api[1].SeriesCollection():
            axisgroup = series.AxisGroup
            if axisgroup == 1:  # primary axis
                chart.api[1].SetElement(msoElementPrimaryValueAxisShow)
                chart.api[1].SetElement(msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisShow)
            elif axisgroup == 2:  # secondary axis
                chart.api[1].SetElement(msoElementSecondaryValueAxisShow)
                # chart.api[1].SetElement(msoElementSecondaryCategoryAxisShow)  # Probably not used

    wb.save(f"out_{filename}")


Thank you, that worked.  I could not find any refernce to 'SetElement'.  Do you have one?  Also, can you explain how you got the element numbers above?  I hate using code without understanding it.  One more thing, any idea how to apply the bold font to those axes values?  Couldn't find that either; can't really find any information on chart.api; just from google searches was I able to piece some of it together.

Xlwings is aka as 'VBA for Excel' using Python. If you don't know what function(s) to use in Xlwings; in Excel, record a macro while executing the required steps and look at the VBA produced. That'll give you the necessary methods for the api. If you are familiar enough with Xlwings you'll know or can look up if what you need  is 'enabled' in Xlwings or if you need to use the api. If not sure check the Xlwings docs or search the internet. If Xlwings supports the method it will often use the same name in all lower case. Of course regardless you can still use the api.

Try it with your bold font requirement, Google the functions used by VBA (or search in SO) to find examples of implementation. If none then change the VBA code to apply using the api.

Thanks, figured that out shortly after asking.  The VBA API reference from MS helped me find the correct function.  chart.api[1].Axes(xl.constants.AxisType.xlCategory, xl.constants.AxisGroup.xlPrimary).TickLabels.Font.Bold = True

Note, Xlwings has a constants.py file you can import that holds the numeric values for most of the Excel enumerations,  but not all of them.

You can add axes to an existing chart in Python using xlwings with chart.api.Axes(1) for the primary X-axis and chart.api.Axes(2) for the primary Y-axis.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.. it's not working for me.  Added x_axis = chart.api[1].Axes(1) and y_axis = chart.api[1].Axes(2)
